# Load timeout for run-time configuration in requirejs

Tags: javascript, html, requirejs

I am getting load timeout error for the run-time configuration and **common.js** is my run-time configuration

As you can see below that I have defined **waitseconds** equal to 0 for the files that will be loaded from common.js however I am getting loadTimeout for the common.js itself.

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/require.js"></script>
    <script>

        require(['./js/common'],
        function (common) {
            'use strict';
            require(['plot/app', 'es6shim']);
        });
    </script>
```

**common.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js',
    waitSeconds: 0,    // Allowing the browser to load all modules without time limit
    paths: {
        // 3rd party
        es6shim: 'vendor/es6-shim.min',
        jquery: 'vendor/jquery-1.10.1.min',
        jqueryUI: 'vendor/jquery-ui.min',
        lodash: 'vendor/lodash.min',
        mockjax: 'vendor/jquery.mockjax',
        hammer: 'vendor/hammer.min'      
    },

    shim: {
        mockjax: { deps: ['jquery'] },
        jqueryUI: { deps: ['jquery'] },
        hammer: { deps: ['jquery', 'jqueryUI'] }
    }
});
```

Let me know what can be done in this case as the **common.js** is itself sometimes not getting loaded and thus throwing load timeout error.

**Note:**- Due to build configuration I am not writing the run-time configuration in the index.html as the configuration(common.js) is common for other app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question does not appear to be seeking to get to the bottom of why `common.js` may be taking so long to retrieve that a timeout is triggered. It seems a litle odd that a timeout should be occurring loading such a simple script, but I assume that is not a concern for you at this point.

To increase the timeout before loading `common.js`, try putting something like the following in `index.html` to provide baseline RequireJS configuration settings to be applied before `common.js` is loaded:

```
<script>
    require = { waitSeconds: 0 };
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/require.js"></script>
...
```

Comment: Thanks Chrisg for the answer. Due to some issue I haven't shared all the js files that I am using in common.js. It is a little odd as I am getting timeout for the common.js file(it doesn't happen always). 
Will update this post when I apply your solution.